# How do I configure a Plastic SCM repository to prevent users from circumventing file locks with distributed workspaces/sync views?

Tags: plasticscm

I do game development with lots of unmergeable binary files. I use locks to prevent merge conflicts, but when new users setup Plastic with a sync view their client ignores the locks and they end up creating conflicts when they try to push their changes to the central repository.

How do I configure my repository to prevent users from being able to create sync views that will conflict this way?

Answer (score 1):

Codice support suggested:

> Deny the "replicateread" permission and they will not be able to locally clone the repository.
>
> [image]